# Terminate debug on device

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm a bit confused about debugging on a device. 
When I use the emulator, after the debug session, I simply close the emulator window...
but when debugging on my device, how can I close the session??simply disconnecting the USB cable?

And the installed .apk ( installed by Eclipse ) should be removed manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by going to the Debug perspective, right clicking your application, and selecting "Disconnect" or "Terminate".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you disconnect, the debug session is terminated.

Any APKs installed during debugging must be removed manually, since technically they're not part of the debugging process.

Comment: So there's no other way in Eclipse right? Anyway thank you :)