# Debug+Unplug vs RUN Android

Tags: android, debugging

I want to know is there some difference between Run and debug + unplug (I mean start debug on device and then unplug the device)?

Answer (score 0):

Device ejecting while debug works like its termination and makes no difference between what Run and Debug has been set. You could check it even without device unplugging (see here [Terminate debug on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640191/terminate-debug-on-device#answer-4640862)).